# Check if two (smart) pointers point to the same derived class

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have a base abstract class `B` and a hundred classes which derive from it `D1` ... `D100`. I also have two (smart) pointers `unique_ptr<B> p1, p2;` which point to two different instances of types `Di` and `Dj`. I want to know whether the objects they're pointing to have the same type (i.e. whether `i` equals `j`). Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: This sounds like a search for a coding solution to a design problem. What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Unique pointer has a `==` operator. Is that what you are trying to achieve? Or do you want to check underlying types of objects pointed to by two unique pointers?

Comment: @Ron that only tells you if they're pointing to the same object, not the same *type* of object.

Comment: @PeteBecker I have a bunch of event classes which inherit from an abstract event. I also have a list of events list<AbstractEvent*> (raw pointers for brevity). I keep adding events to the end of the list. When I add certain special events, I want to ignore all preexisting events and remove all events of this type from the list.

Comment: @MarkRansom- If the OP's code has two pointers that point to the same object, but somehow not the same *type* of object, Pete's observation becomes all the more apparent.

Comment: Are you looking for [std::is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a RTTI typeid, but generally, it is a bad design to must have to use dynamic_cast because it may violate the liskov substitution principle

```
std::unique_ptr<B> p1, p2;
if(typeid(*p1) == typeid(*p2)) // correction by Justin
```

Or something like that using `name` or `hash_code`

Comment: I'm not seeing how dynamic_cast can help me here without trying it a hundred times

Comment: It's not obvious how to use a dynamic cast to solve the problem. Show some code.

Comment: I'm unsure, but I think that `typeid(ptrType)` doesn't find the most derived type; you should use `typeid(referenceType)`: `typeid(*p1)`

Comment: Normally, typeid used on a polymorphic type resolve the vtable to know the exact type.

Comment: Note that the base class would have to have a virtual function anyway: it's destructor would have to virtual to be used in a `unique_ptr`

Answer (score 5):

Checking C++ RTTI is relatively expensive and cumbersome: consider adding an event tag in the base class, and checking for that value.

```
enum class EventTag {
    A, B
};

struct EventBase {
    const EventTag tag;
    EventBase(EventTag tag) : tag(tag) {
    }
};

struct EventA : public EventBase {
    EventA() : EventBase(EventTag::A) {
    }
};

struct EventB : public EventBase {
    EventB() : EventBase(EventTag::B) {
    }
};

if (thisEvent->tag == thatEvent->tag) {
    // stuff
}
```

A union instead of a class hierarchy could also do it for you.

Comment: So to avoid RTTI, let's implement it ourselves?

Comment: How is RTTI more expensive than calling a virtual method?

Comment: @StoryTeller, you're welcome to post a solution that does use C++'s RTTI.

Comment: @StoryTeller, then it seems that there is no problem. The fact that you prefer to use built-in RTTI doesn't make the built-in RTTI the universal solution. I didn't make up this pattern here, massive C++ codebases like LLVM use it.

Comment: @MarkRansom, see [assembly for typeid](https://godbolt.org/g/4PGmF4) vs [assembly for tag](https://godbolt.org/g/35kqWF).

Comment: Fine, you may have a point when it comes optimizing tight loops. But the mere mention of "expensive and cumbersome" should also be qualified with *this solution* being expansive to apply on an existing code base (the OP's case), and then making the class design itself more cumbersome (it has to be designed with this in mind, after all). Also, that non-const tag in your sample is really irksome. I can already imagine someone running with his and changing an objects type on the fly.

Comment: @StoryTeller, the `const` qualifier is an easy fix, that I've just done (thanks for pointing it out). Of course, adding a tag has a cost, but it's a very visible cost, so anyone who's considering going for either `typeid` or this solution has everything in hand to decide what's the best for their own circumstances.

Comment: Oh, there's a not so visible cost too. Not just in implementing the type info. That tag (that we agree should be `const`), prevents c'tors and assignment operators from being defaulted (implicitly or explicitly). That's a noticeable burden if the hierarchy is large and stuff should be copyable/movable.

Comment: This is a better solution than I initially thought you were proposing. For some strange reason, I thought you were saying to provide a virtual function `tag()`. The assemblies are very similar in size if you use typeid and a virtual tag function, but there might be a slight edge to the typeid due to not having to call a function (there's more indirection and branches, though, so idk which is faster assembly). This solution you are proposing completely avoids the need for virtual functions or RTTI, which is huge.

Comment: @Justin I made the same mistake at first. Admittedly this is going to be more efficient than a virtual function or RTTI, but *how much* more? Virtual functions wouldn't be part of the language if they imposed an unacceptable burden.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a little convoluted at first but it can ensure the operability of what you are looking for in the terms of comparisons. There is a little more overhead to this approach in maintainability, but it will ensure proper comparison without too much overhead of execution in regards of time execution.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class AbstractBase {
public:
    enum DerivedTypes {
        DERIVED_A,
        DERIVED_B
    };

protected:
    DerivedTypes type_;

public:
    explicit AbstractBase( const DerivedTypes type ) : type_( type ) {}

    virtual void print() = 0;

    DerivedTypes getType() const {
        return type_;
    }   

    bool operator==( const AbstractBase& other ) {
        return this->type_ == other.getType();
    }
};

class DerivedA : public AbstractBase {
public:
    const int x = 5;

public:
    explicit DerivedA( const DerivedTypes type = DerivedTypes::DERIVED_A ) : AbstractBase( type ) {}

    virtual void print() override {
        std::cout << "DerivedA\n";
    } 
};

class DerivedB : public AbstractBase {
public:
    const float y = 1.5f;

public:
    explicit DerivedB( const DerivedTypes type = DerivedTypes::DERIVED_B ) : AbstractBase( type ) {}

    virtual void print() override {
        std::cout << "DerivedB\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<DerivedA> p1 = std::make_unique<DerivedA>( DerivedA() );
    std::unique_ptr<DerivedB> p2 = std::make_unique<DerivedB>( DerivedB() );

    p1->print();
    p2->print();

    if ( *p1 == *p2  ) {
        std::cout << "pointers are the same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "pointers are not the same\n";
    }

    std::unique_ptr<DerivedA> p3 = std::make_unique<DerivedA>( DerivedA() );
    std::unique_ptr<DerivedA> p4 = std::make_unique<DerivedA>( DerivedA() );

    p3->print();
    p4->print();

    if ( *p3 == *p4 ) {
        std::cout << "pointers are the same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "pointers are not the same\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The added cost here of the maintainability depends on how many derived classes there are. If this design pattern is used from the beginning it is quite easy to follow. If one has to modify a numerable amount of classes it will take some time and effort to modify the existing code base.

The idea here is that the abstract base class keeps an internal variable of the derived type, has a getter for it's derived type & an overloaded == comparison operator that compares the types. The constructor is forced to take its enumerated type as well as all the derived types. I also defaulted the derived types so that it doesn't have to be passed to their constructors every time a class object is instantiated. This is the overhead of the maintainability.

The simplicity of this comes into play when comparing pointers - smart pointers of multiple derived types. When you look at the main function above you can see that it was simple enough to dereference the smart pointers and the base class's overloaded == operator takes care of business.

If one does need to use the `operator==()` to actually compare numerical differences between classes then this can be modified to use a public method in the base class that compares the types and returns a bool instead of the overloaded operator.